# In Operator in Linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I tried to use the suggestion provided here for using In operator in  linq but, i am not able to convert my requirement into LINQ statement.

Below is the SQL query which i need to convert to Linq

```
select *
from   navigator_user_field_property
where  user_id = 'albert'
and    field_id in (
       select field_id
       from   navigator_entity_field_master 
       where  entity_id = 1
       and    use_type = 0)
order by field_id
```

I want this to be converted to a Efficient Linq.

Most of the answers deal with the predetermined list of string array which is not working in my case.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a join to me:

```
var query = from navigator in db.NavigatorUserFieldProperties
            where navigator.UserId == "albert"
            join field in db.NavigatorEntityFieldMasters
                            .Where(f => f.EntityId == 1 && f.UseType == 0)
            on navigator.FieldId equals field.FieldId
            select navigator;
```

Note that this will return the same value multiple times if there are multiple fields with the same ID - but I suspect that's not the case.

You *could* do a more literal translation like this:

```
var query = from navigator in db.NavigatorUserFieldProperties
            where navigator.UserId == "albert" &&
                db.NavigatorEntityFieldMasters
                  .Where(f => f.EntityId == 1 && f.UseType == 0)
                  .select(f => f.FieldId)
                  .Contains(navigator.FieldId)
            select navigator;
```

... and that *may* end up translating to the same SQL... but I'd personally go with the join.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an efficient and readable LINQ query:

```
var fields = 
    from field in db.navigator_entity_field_masters
    where field.entity_id == 1 && field.user_type == 0
    select field;

var properties =
    from property in db.navigator_user_field_properties
    where property.user_id == "albert"
    where fields.Contains(property.field)
    select property;
```

Look mama!! Without joins ;-)

Comment: There is a reason joins exist at the SQL level. I could be wrong, but this could potentially lead to degenerate performance in the case where only a (small) fraction of the records pulled are really matches. If that is the case, then "efficient" should be prefaced with the conditions.

Comment: @pst: I don't think you understand LINQ (over expression trees). When you think that all fields are pulled from the database then you are wrong. LINQ to SQL will transform this to a very performand (and single) query. Also note that LINQ to SQL will transform this to a SQl query with joins, and is able to do this because of the meta data of the generated model.